# generate the 6 digit random as a new column in the my data frame in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have huge data in my dataframe now i want to try to insert the new column with 6 digit random.
i've tried with lit(randrange(99999)) is not working as expected, it's producing lesser than the 6 digit as well static value been produced to entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use built-in spark function rand() to get desired result.

```
spark.sql("select ceil(rand() * 1000000)").show()
```

To add this to new column:
Assuming df as your dataframe:

```
df.withColumn("random6digit",ceil(rand() * 1000000))
```